# showing name of an object on gui in tcl/tk

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

How can I get/show name of an object(variable name) on gui?

> This is object name "frame"

```
  set frame [.c1 create rectangle 50 50 200 200 -width 4 -outline "red"]
```

when i click on this, it will show its name in a text box or with mouse pointer. How can it be possible? please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you are doing, or what you want to happen.

I assume that you have created a canvas `.c1`, that you have successfully displayed it in a toplevel window somewhere and that you want to respond when the user clicks **on the border** of the rectangle you have created.

In that case, you need to specify a binding for the click on the item

```
.c1 bind $frame <button-1> {puts stdout "The frame has been clicked"}
```

This will just print a message on the console, which is enough to prove the mechanism. You'll need to decide how you want to display it.

Alternatively, use the tooltip package from tklib, documented [here](http://tcllib.sourceforge.net/doc/tooltip.html), via

```
tooltip::tooltip .c1 -items $frame "The frame has been hovered over"
```

which will display "The frame has been..." if the user hovers over **the border** of the frame.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to show a varying string in the GUI is to use a label with the `-textvariable` option set. Then you can just set a variable and the string will appear.

To respond to a click, a canvas item should have an event handler script bound to it. The most common events to bind to are `<ButtonPress>` — often written `<1>` for `<ButtonPress-1>`, which is the main mouse button — and `<Enter>` and `<Leave>`, which handle tracking of what the mouse is over. The `current` canvas tag tracks the current item (if any).

Combining these:

```
pack [canvas .c1]
# make some items here...
.c1 create rectangle 50 50 200 200 -width 4 -outline "red"
# ...

pack [frame .f1 -textvariable msg]
.c1 bind all <1> {set msg "Click on %W:[%W finditem current]"}
.c1 bind all <Enter> {set msg "Entered %W:[%W finditem current]"}
.c1 bind all <Leave> {set msg ""}
```

When you're experimenting with this, be sure to check out entirely transparent items (particularly fully transparent polygons). They're useful for defining hot areas that are invisible to the user, a pretty useful technique especially if they're put on top of several other items that are visible…